# Safari Cannot Load XMLHttpRequest Due to Access Control Checks

Tags: ajax, search, safari, typeahead.js, typeahead

I am running into an issue that only occurs on Safari when searching on the website. It also only occurs when a user types and presses enter faster than the search suggestions can load.

The error we receive is: "XMLHTTPRequest cannot load [URL]/?query=testing due to access control checks. All requests are on the same domain so I do not believe this is a CORS problem. Also it appears to happen during the remote function and not the prefetch due error containing /query

The typeahead configuration is found below:

```
            $('#searchIconInput').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'searchSuggestionsShown',
            source: searchSuggestionEngine
        });
    });

        var searchSuggestionEngine = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveSuggestedSearchItems", "Search")',
            ttl: getNumberOfMillisecondsToCachePrefetchedData(),
        },
        remote: {
            url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveAdditionalSuggestedSearchItems", "Search")/?query=',
            replace: function (url, uriEncodedQuery) {
                return url + uriEncodedQuery;
            },
            cache: false
        }
    });
```